# R studio graph not plotted (neither with x11())

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

```
p <- data %>%
ggplot(aes(x=rating)) +
geom_histogram( binwidth=10, fill="#69b3a2", color="#e9ecef", alpha=0.9) +
ggtitle("Distribution of teams fifa ratings") +
theme_ipsum() + theme(plot.title = element_text(size=15))
```

#I am trying to plot this histogram but I don't know why the plot is not shown
#This code unlikely contains mistakes since I have copied It from https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/220-basic-ggplot2-histogram.html#binSize

Comment: did you call p?

Comment: yes and nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

Your `binwidth` argument is the culprit. You can confirm by removing that and seeing if it works.

Set a `binwidth` that is compatible with the values for `rating`. This should solve the issue.